# vertical and horizontal centering datalist box with its button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Trying to style my datalist by aligning it to the center(vertically and horizontally) but i could only do horizontal centering not vertical.

Is there a way to increase the width of datalist box and do some styling. Please help..

```js
$('#btn').click(function() { // The `$` reference here is a jQuery syntax. So we are loading jquery right before this script tag
        var textval = $('#textcat').val();
        window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="text-center">
    <input list="category" name="category" id="textcat" placeholder="Enter your area..">
    <datalist id="category">
      <option id="www.google.com" value="fruits" />
      <option id="www.fb.com" value="animals" />
      <option id="www.ymail.com" value="vechiles" />
      <option id="www.msn.com" value="ornaments" />
    </datalist>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="submit">
  
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the datalist vertically, use `display: flex` and `align-items: center`. Note that you need to set a height on your container to align its contents vertically.

Just noticed your note about width. To tweak that, you can just adjust the width property using your datalist's id.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh1fw9a3/1/).

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Could i make this mobile responsive

Answer (score 2):

In the "Input" element, you can adjust the element width according to your preferences easily.

Refer this page for more information
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp

```js
$('#btn').click(function() { // The `$` reference here is a jQuery syntax. So we are loading jquery right before this script tag
  var textval = $('#textcat').val();
  window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 25%">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="text-center">
        <input style="width: 100%" list="category" name="category" id="textcat" placeholder="Enter your area..">
        <datalist id="category">
          <option id="www.google.com" value="fruits" />
          <option id="www.fb.com" value="animals" />
          <option id="www.ymail.com" value="vechiles" />
          <option id="www.msn.com" value="ornaments" />
        </datalist>
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: through your answer i could able to increase the width, but the vertical centering i couldnot get. Is there something i miss

Comment: check the code now... i changed the row class padding settings